# How to change the size of tablayout icon

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using a tablayout with a viewpager. The icons namely notification icon and message icon change when there is a new message or notification. I replace the icons with the similar icon but with a badge. This is what the icons look like without the bage:

[image]

Now the issue is that the icons with the badge appear smaller in size as shown in the image below

[image]

Though the difference is very small but I have to get the icons the same size. I figured the icons are the same size but the badges take up the space and make the icons smaller. I'm using `tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.messageWhite);`to set the icons.
I tried to use custom view which fix the problem but then I have issue changing the custom view dynamically.
Is there a way I can define the size of the icon using `setIcon' property?`

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the view of your tab item first.After that you can set your icon in respective imageview in your custom tab item view.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_horizontal,null);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);
    TextView text_tab_item = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_tab_item);
    ImageView img_tabtxt = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_tabtxt);
    img_tabtxt.setImageResource(R.drawable.request_tab_white);
    text_tab_item.setText("Members");
    text_tab_item.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_color));
```